# why am i getting the error of below code ;

Tags: java, oop

Here's the program in which I am getting an error:

// import Scanner Class
import java.util.Scanner;

```
// creating ClassStudent1
class ClassStudent1 {

    // creating instance variable for ClassStudent1 class
    int id;
    String name;

}

// creating another class in which main() will be present
class Student2{

    // creating main() method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating Scanner Class object
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        // creating ClassStudent1 object
        ClassStudent stu = new ClassStudent();

        // asigning value to the ClassStudent1 object stu
        stu.name="jay";
        stu.id=1023;

        // printing the value which is asign to the object
        System.out.println(stu.id);
        System.out.println(stu.name);

        // asigning value to the Scanner Class object
        System.out.println("enter your name");
        String b=sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("enter your id");
        int a=sc.nextInt();

        stu.id = a;
        stu.name = b;

       System.out.println("your id is:",a);
      //  System.out.println("your name is:",b);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

these are the errors that I am getting:

```
java: no suitable method found for println(java.lang.String,int)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(char) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(float) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(char[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: I like your comments. 100% correct but give no information whatsoever.

Comment: System.out.println("your id is:",+a);

Comment: `System.out.println("Your id is: " + Integer.tostring(a));`

Comment: Please format your code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
System.out.println("your id is:",+a);
```

[Check out this link for how to use println](https://java2blog.com/system-out-println-java/)

Comment: Don't just provide links, explain the key information which can be found there. If the link dies, your answer will become useless without it.